# not able to make union of two queries in sql using group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having

```
select sum(total) from (
(select sum(team1_score) as total from country,match_results where country_name=team1 group by country_name as s1)
UNION ALL
(select sum(team2_score) as total from country,match_results where country_name=team2 group by country_name as s2)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the second alias in select and the alias for group by  and assigna proper name to the  subquery from

```
select sum(total) from (
  select sum(team1_score) as total 
  from country,match_results 
  where country_name=team1 
  group by country_name 
  UNION ALL
  select sum(team2_score) 
  from country,match_results 
  where country_name=team2 
  group by country_name 
) T
```

You should use explicit inner join

```
select sum(total) from (
   select sum(team1_score) as total 
   from country
   inner join match_results on  country.country_name=team1 and 
   match_results.team1=team1
   group by country_name 
UNION ALL
   select sum(team2_score) 
   from country
   inner join match_results on  country.country_name=team2 and 
   match_results.team2=team2
   group by country_name 
) T
```

Comment: Great thanks scaisEdge, Both solutions work very well now. But in second suggestion of using inner join can you explain why to use two conditions 
country.country_name=team2 and match_results.team2=team2 ??

Comment: is the same  ..  i hav eopted  for this because is more simple to understand  but you can use also  from country   inner join match_results on  country.country_name= match_results.country_name and country.country_name =team1 ... is the same ... using  the transitive property or not the result don't change

Answer (score 1):

Try removing aliases i.e. `as s1` and `as s2`

Answer (score 0):

The aliases should be outside the subqueries; MySQL likely thinks you are trying to (pointlessly) alias the grouping criteria.